# How to add a custom html mark to the tradingview

Tags: tradingview-api

In the react framework, how do you add a custom html mark to the tradingvie arealine diagram? I looked at the shap and mark in the api and it seems that it cannot customize content with styles (such as a combination of pictures and text). I hope to get your help. Thank you so much

The following is my current code, which can only form a circle mark, which does not meet my needs:

```
    getMarks: (symbolInfo, startDate, endDate, onDataCallback, resolution) => {
        console.log('getMarks', symbolInfo, startDate, endDate, onDataCallback, resolution);
        var Arr = [
            {
                id: 1,
                time: Date.now() / 1000 - 45,
                color: 'red',
                text: '<div>3333</div>',
                label: 'test',
                labelFontColor: 'yellow',
                minSize: 30,
            },
        ]
        let res = onDataCallback(Arr);
        console.log(res, "=====getMarks running");
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the appearance of marks in the area line diagram, so you need to use the "plothtml" data feed property:

```
getMarks: (symbolInfo, startDate, endDate, onDataCallback, resolution) => {
const customMarks = [
    {
        id: 1,
        time: Date.now() / 1000 - 45,
        color: 'transparent', // Set the color to transparent
        text: '<div style="background: #f0f0f0; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px;">Custom Mark</div>', // Your custom HTML content
        label: 'test',
        labelFontColor: 'yellow',
        minSize: 30,
        shape: 'arrowUp', // You can use different shapes like arrowUp
    },
];

// Use plothtml to pass the custom HTML content
customMarks.forEach((mark) => {
    mark.plothtml = mark.text;
});

// Pass the custom marks to the chart using onDataCallback
onDataCallback(customMarks);
},
```